# Best way to figure out what css is being applied to an element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, browser

I started building a site using a bootstrap template, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to tweak the css. For example, a table might stretch across the entire page. But when I use F12 to look at the css, I don't see anything related to a width property anywhere around the table. Is there a better way to determine what css is being applied or inherited?

Comment: this question is not related to html, css or bootstrap rather then browsers-tools

Comment: Try looking under the `Computed` styles tab/section in the DOM/Elements pane. Chrome and FF dev tools both have this feature in some way. IE technically does too, but it's not as nice and clutters in other information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this Chrome plugin called [SnappySnippet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snappysnippet/blfngdefapoapkcdibbdkigpeaffgcil?hl=en).  (Also, prepare to be amazed)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Google Chrome element inspector. Right click on a `div` or any other page element, and then click "Inspect Element". From there you can view the CSS that is being applied to a specific element.

Comment: Also you can check the computed styles and search for width

Answer (score 0):

Have a look inside bootstrap.css file , there should be plenty of code and not every element has it's own separate css , some elements are defined together

Answer (score 0):

If you use google dev tools (F12), the navigation tab will let you click on "Resources." When you click that, you can look at the scripts, stylesheets, see a list of images used, etc...

if you click the "magnifying glass" in Google dev tools (F12), you can hover over any element on the page. Click that element and on the right side, the CSS will be displayed. Usually the stylesheet is called out inside the css.